# How to check if an identical element exists in another table in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I have two models: CaseRequest and Case. The `CaseRequest` object has values `name` and `datebirth`. I need to check if the same values exists for `name` and `datebirth` in `Case`. For instance, The result should be like this:

Case:

```
Name DateBirth
Don Honn 01.03.1959
Freak Hu 04.11.1993
Wend Don 06.03.1988
```

CaseRequest:

```
Name DateBirth 
Tom Hawk 01.05.1999 - no
Don Honn 01.03.1959 - yes
Fold Len 03.07.1967 - no
Freak Hu 04.11.1993 - yes
Wend Don 13.12.1956 - no
```

My code:
`Models.py`

```
class CaseRequest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datebirth = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timeapplication = models.DateField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('caserequest')

class Case(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datebirth = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' | ' + str(self.datebirth)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('case_list')
```

`Views.py`

```
class CaseRequestView(ListView):
    model = CaseRequest
    template_name = 'caserequest.html'
```

`caserequest.html`

```
<div>
  {% for caserequest in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>{{ caserequest.name }}, {{ caserequest.datebirth }}</p>
            <!-- The result should be here: YES or NO -->
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey You can ignore 'status', it's just an extraneous characteristic.

Comment: So what's your problem, I am not able to understand, can you clarify?

Comment: In the HTML form, I want each `caserequest` to show `yes` or `no`, depending on whether the same `name` and `datebirth` exist in the `Case` table.

Comment: Do you mean in comparison to previous instances? For e.g. if name is `rhaul` and `date` is `1996/09/09` then it should show `no` and  if the second instance has the same name and date then it should show "yes"? Do you want this?

Comment: I think yes. I'll clarify again. Each object in the `CaseRequest` is compared for the identical name and date in the `Case`, and if there are identical values, then the response in html is yes, otherwise no

Comment: Compared to single previous instance or all the instances present in the model?

Comment: all the instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a `@property` decorator, say for example `case_exists` in the models so:

```py
class CaseRequest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datebirth = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timeapplication = models.DateField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('caserequest')
    
    @property
    def case_exists(self):
        return Case.objects.filter(name=self.name, datebirth=self.datebirth).exists()
```

Then in the template use it as:

```html
<div>
    {% for caserequest in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>{{ caserequest.name }}, {{ caserequest.datebirth }} - {% if caserequest.case_exists %} Yes {% else %} No {% endif %}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`I think you must to create a py file called utils.py or similar in same directory where you have view.py with following code:`

```
from django import template
from ptii.models import Case

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def get_case(caserequest_name, caserequest_datebirth):
    if Case.objects.filter(name=caserequest_name).filter(
            datebirth=caserequest_datebirth).exists():
        return('Yes')
    else:
        return('No')
```

and in your html you have to load the file utils.py and use the function like this:

```
{% load utils.py %} {# load the file #}

{% get_case caserequest.name caserequest_datebirth as exist %} {# get Yes or No #}
```

Then you can use exist field in yout html as this:

{{ exist }}

Comment: Thank you for feedback, however, I have an eror during html loading - TemplateSyntaxError at /caserequest/
'utils.py' is not a registered tag library.

Comment: And what is ptii?

Comment: ptii is the name of my app, you have to use the name of your app

Comment: Yes, I removed it. And I tried to connect utils.py file. I wrote 'libraries':  { 'compare': 'social.utils.simple', } in TEMPLATES in settings.py. But there is an error:   No module named 'social.utils.simple'; 'social.utils' is not a package